# OpenCSV Write to other column

Tags: java, opencsv

I want to Read a CSV file and write a String to the next column in the same csv file.

```
        FsmMorphologicalAnalyzer fsm = new FsmMorphologicalAnalyzer();

        try{
          CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/Users/asus/Desktop/morfolojik-veri.csv"));
          CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/asus/Desktop/morfolojik-veri.csv"), '\t');

          String [] nextLine;
          while ((nextLine=reader.readNext()) != null){

              if (nextLine != null) {
                  FsmParseList fsmParseList = fsm.morphologicalAnalysis(nextLine[0]);
                  if (fsmParseList.size() != 0) {
                      FsmParse parse = fsmParseList.getFsmParse(0);
                      String result = parse.root.toString();
                      String temp [] = {result.substring(0, result.indexOf(' '))};
                      writer.writeNext(temp);
                  }
                  else {
                      System.out.println("Nothing");
                  }
              }
          }

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

But this clears all the file when i execute.
Also it shows me a Warning as:

csvwriter(java.io.Writer,char) is deprecated.

Should i write it to new csv but i want to keep them side by side. Like the first column will be the read one, the second column will be the written.

EDIT: Before program starts morfolojik-veri looks like:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO31h.png)

[What i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVOV9.png)

But all i need is how can i append in new column or write in a new csv file.

(Sorry about my English)
Thanks.

Comment: what version are you implementing?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ4.6

Comment: Maybe you can post part of file `morfolojik-veri.csv` to show what it looks like before running your program and also post what you want it to look like after your program finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenCSV very often. What you are doing is not the way to go. 
Just read the input file and while doing that write to another/output file.

Once fully done (with processing the input file):
1) delete the old/input file (or rename it to another, non-conflicting name);
2) rename the new/output file to the old filename.

That's how you can do it most easily.